# Creating video recording from website analytics

Tags: javascript, video-capture, screencast

I have recorded coordinates and time-stamp of every mouse move on a web page, together with the website document and other relative data. Using this data how can I generate a screen cast/video of the user interactions with the website?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it with http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page.
It would be much easier to just record the screen as video.